# How is the color pattern applied to this product?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, product-engineering, product-design

I am new to product design and injection molding, and am only familiar with basic finishing options such as painting, pad printing, and uv printing for decorating consumer products. I found this speaker with a complex surface pattern and I was wondering how it was achieved.

[image: Red Speaker]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Looks like ink - probably pad printing or screen printing

Answer (score 1):

As CBRF23 mentioned, I think it's screen printing.  This involves pushing ink through a porous mesh.  For circular parts such as this, the part would be rotating along the screen as a squeegee pushed the ink through the screen and onto the part.

This is a good example of how this process can be accomplished:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ozy9LWwyMiw

Comment: Do special measures need to be taken to apply this to a textured surface such as the one OP has linked, instead of a 'smooth' surface like shown in the video you linked?

Answer (score 0):

That is an outer cover, so it could easily be made of some flexible plastic on a substrate.

Have you been to a shop to hold the product or you are just guessing based on a picture?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean flexible plastic on a substrate?